# Not returning correct selected value in android

Tags: android

Hi In the below code friend array having two values user3 and user1 with checkboxes.When I am selecting user1 means second checkbox it showing check variable value user3.

how to get exactly which user I got selected.where I did mistake

**java**

```
    public class GroupList extends ListActivity 
    {

        boolean[] checkBoxState;
        boolean isChecked;

        int position;
        private IAppManager imService = null;

        private FriendListAdapter friendAdapter;

        public String ownusername = new String();

        private class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
        {   
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")

            class ViewHolder {
                TextView text;
                ImageView icon;
                CheckBox check1;



            }

            private LayoutInflater mInflater;
            private Bitmap mOnlineIcon;
            private Bitmap mOfflineIcon;        

            private FriendInfo[] friends = null;





            public FriendListAdapter(Context context) {
                super();            

                mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

                mOnlineIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.greenstar);
                mOfflineIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.redstar);

            }

            public void setFriendList(FriendInfo[] friends)
            {
                this.friends = friends;

            }


            public int getCount() {     

                return friends.length;
            }


            public FriendInfo getItem(int position) {           

                return friends[position];
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {

                return 0;
            }

            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                final ViewHolder holder;


                if (convertView == null) 
                {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grouplist, null);


                    holder = new ViewHolder();

                    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                    holder.check1 = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);

                }           

                else {

                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

                }


                holder.text.setText(friends[position].userName);
                holder.icon.setImageBitmap(friends[position].status == STATUS.ONLINE ? mOnlineIcon : mOfflineIcon);


                checkBoxState = new boolean[friends.length];
                holder.check1.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
                holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        checkBoxState[position]=isChecked;




                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),friends[position].userName+"checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });


                return convertView;
            }

        }
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.group_list_screen);

        Button create=(Button)findViewById(R.id.create);
        create.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String groupname = getIntent().getStringExtra("nick");


                        try {

                            FriendInfo[] friend=FriendController.getFriendsInfo();

                            String check=friend[position].userName;
                            String result1 = imService.CreateGroup(groupname,imService.getUsername(),check);
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Group Created Sucessfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });


        friendAdapter = new FriendListAdapter(this);




    }
```

Comment: where does `position` variable come from? Could be position is broken! If you share more code, it would be easier to understand where the broken part is

Comment: @AdemIlhan did you saw the edited post

Comment: you have to tell us how you get int position variable for this:
String check=friend[position].userName;

Comment: when I am selecting the user3 I want to get the value as user3 same as user1 also happens this is my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok - I know what you want to do - but your approach is very complicated.

Make FriendListAdapter simpler - create XML layout resources for your row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:drawableRight="@drawable/checked_box"
android:text="">
</CheckedTextView>
```

Next create in drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked"/>
</selector>
```

in your java code after creating and setting adapter you could retrive checked items by listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

Comment: Thanks for giving suggestion but my code where i did mistake that one i want to know?

Comment: I cant see your whole code but I think that in onCreate() in String check=friend[position].userName; line you are giving wrong position - I cant see where this variable comes from...

Comment: when I am selecting the user3 Toast message coming correctly which user I am selecting it giving the particular user got checked.The same like that I want to pass the parameter which one got selected with group name main username

Comment: ok - you don't get me :) variable int position in your adapter is NOT the same variable as position in onCreate()! To test it put Log.d("debug", "Adapter position: "  + position); in adapter and in onCreate() Log.d("debug", "OnCreate position: "  + position);

Comment: Small doubt how to get the two values at a time user3,user1